# Transform a Pandas DataFrame with Sequential Data to a DataFrame with Multiple Columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have read some data into a Pandas dataframe (from a SQL database). The data is sequential in the following form:

### Symbol | Data_Time |   Value

AA  |    2016-11-09 09:30:00  | 1

AA  |    2016-11-09 09:45:00  | 2

AA  |    2016-11-09 10:00:00  | 5

...

BB  |     2016-11-09 09:30:00  | 3

BB  |     2016-11-09 09:45:00  | 6

BB  |    2016-11-09 10:00:00   | 8

...

Is there an easy way to transform the data to

### Data_Time      |       AA  |BB

2016-11-09 09:30:00 |  1  | 3

2016-11-09 09:45:00 |  2  | 6

2016-11-09 10:00:00 |  5  | 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need pivot

```
df.pivot(index = 'Data_Time', columns = 'Symbol', values = 'Value').reset_index()
```

You get

```
Symbol  Data_Time            AA  BB
0       2016-11-09 09:30:00  1   3
1       2016-11-09 09:45:00  2   6
2       2016-11-09 10:00:00  5   8
```

Another way:

```
df.set_index(['Data_Time', 'Symbol']).Value.unstack().reset_index()
```

Comment: In the resulting dataframe, if I want to compare values from each row at lets say 10:00:00 everyday to the prior day at 9:30:00, is there an easy way to do or should I run a for loop?

Comment: Glad it worked and thank you for accepting. For the second question, there is almost always a non-loop way to handle things in Pandas but its better that you post a question with the sample data and expected output. Its easier to test out the code that way

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Will do.

Comment: Here is the link to the new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186750/comparing-data-across-dates-at-different-times